# How to run full SSD disk check with `fsck` command on system reboot (Debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, filesystems, fsck

Please advice how to run full SSD disk check with `fsck` command on system reboot? (Debian) sdb2 is root, sdb1 is boot partitions. What is recommended options and where to find check report? I would prefer to create report file in home directory. I did check, but two files in Debian **fsck** folder does not have much useful info(plus require admin priveleges to access it):

```
Log of fsck -C -f -a -t ext4 /dev/sdb2 
Sat Oct 17 22:34:36 2015

fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
ROOT: 112816/2498560 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 955505/9984000 blocks

Sat Oct 17 22:34:39 2015
===========
Log of fsck -C -R -A -a -f 
Sat Oct 17 22:34:39 2015

fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
BOOT: 240/128000 files (1.3% non-contiguous), 32629/256000 blocks

Sat Oct 17 22:34:40 2015
```